# Object functions fail within LINQ to Entities Expressions

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

**PLEASE NOTE**: I know how to work around this. I am NOT looking for a solution, I am looking for clarity on the problem itself.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new TestDbContext())
        {
            var eventsFound = context.Events
                .Where(e => 
                    e.EventDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) && 
                    e.EventDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1)
                )
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
}
```

Ok, so the above program fails with:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)'
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Why can LINQ not tell the difference between a database function and an object function.  The system should be clever enough to realize that the AddDays function is part of the DateTime object.  It should then first resolve that function and then once all functions in the query are resolved, convert to SQL and execute that against the database.

I'm sure it's a lot more complicated than that but I would like to understand why.

========= EDIT ==============

So the above was not actually a good example as "AddDays" is a function which exists in both .NET and SQL.  What about when I change it to a self defined function where no ambiguity could exist.

ie:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReturnDateNowExample()
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myEvent = new Event {EventDate = new DateTime(2013, 08, 28)};
    using (var context = new TestDbContext())
    {
        var eventsFound = context.Events
            .Where(e =>
                e.EventDate >= myEvent.ReturnDateNowExample()
            )
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

And it if is the DateTime object that is ambiguous, then replace with a string/int object.

Comment: I appreciate that you want an explanation but as a temporary fix you could make two DateTime variables at the beginning of your function. I'm not savvy on the particulars of linq but I imagine comparing against two local variables has to be quicker than having it evaluate the function for each object in the list (if that's what it does).

Comment: Just to be clear, I know how to work around this.  I am not looking for a solution, I am looking for clarity on the problem itself.

Comment: Note that under LINQ-to-SQL it works correctly, so you should remove the LINQ-to-SQL tag.

Comment: Oops, I wasn't looking.  It has been removed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this has nothing to do with it being "clever", and more to do with the way Linq works.  Linq uses something called an "expression tree".  Basically, it compiles your expression down to a set of data, which is then converted by a translation layer into SQL.

The reason this doesn't work is because this is in a where clause, and the where clause must be executed in SQL to be accurate.  It cannot be executed in C# code on the back end, at least not without silently returning all rows of the table, which would not be a desired functionality... and if it is, you can tell it to do this explicitly.

Entity Framework provides a set of functions for working with dates that CAN be converted directly to SQL, and these are in the EntityFunctions namespace.  These map to so-called "canonical functions" which just means that there are 1:1 translations to SQL.  Linq to Sql passes the client-side evaluated where clause as a parameter, but this may or may not be the desired value because you may need a server-side value rather than a client-side calculated value.. thus L2S will give you unexpected results in some situations.

Simply put, you need special expression functions to be able to convert to SQL, and just any old standard .NET classes won't work, which the DateTime classes are, unfortunately.

You might find the following articles useful:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx

http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/21a9c660-13e5-4751-aa51-6519bddae044/enterprise-framework-linq-queries-failing

Comment: This works correctly in LINQ to SQL and it uses expression trees too.  It's intelligent enough to know when a function call is going to return a primitive, and wraps the result up into a parameter to pass into SQL.  This is also possible in Entity Framework, it's just the development team made a design decision not to implement this behaviour.

Comment: @DoctorJones - Wrong, it does not work correctly.  Because Linq to Sql evaluates the DateTime functions on the client, that means the values passed are client values, not server values.  DateFunctions in EF are Server values, and are the expected result of a translation to SQL.  This is one of the major faults of Linq to Sql.  You see it as a benefit, but nearly any database person would see it as a flaw.

Comment: @MystereMan, thanks for your answer.  I guess what I am asking is why does it have to be so rigid and only accept SQL queries.  I would expect there to be some middle ground or a amalgamation of the 2 systems.  If it's an object, remove it from the expression tree and resolve it first and use the result in the expression tree.

Comment: @Talon - Linq to Sql is what's known as a "hybrid" parser, as it allows evaluation of parameters while parsing.  This means it's not a true Expression tree parser.  Still, you may find this article helpful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/21a9c660-13e5-4751-aa51-6519bddae044/enterprise-framework-linq-queries-failing - In there it says this:  "This makes the boundary between client and store evaluation explicit. There is a tradeoff between self-containment of queries and predictability of behavior for non-expert users."  This suggests its to prevent users from shooting themselves

Comment: @Talon - It seems to me that the EF team has chosen to keep expression parsing explicit to prevent situations where the client intended for something to be done on the server, but it was done on the client.  It's very easy in Linq to Sql to end up using client-side dates rather than server-side dates, as an example.

Comment: @MystereMan, I have edited my original question.  I think the problem was the ambiguity of the "AddDays" function existing on both client and server. Perhaps though, due to being safe for one situation, they had to apply the same logic to all.

Answer (score 6):

It's interesting to note the different query generated by LINQ-to-SQL and by Entity Framework if we use directly `DateTime.Now` in a query:

LINQ-to-SQL:

```
WHERE ([t0].[EventDate] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[EventDate] <= @p1)
```

Entity Framework

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[EventDate] >= CAST( SysDateTime() AS datetime2)) AND ([Extent1].[EventDate] <= CAST( SysDateTime() AS datetime2))
```

The difference here is that LINQ-to-SQL considers the `DateTime.Now` something that must be calculated .NET-side and sent as a parameter of the query, while EF considers the `DateTime.Now` something that can be calculated SQL-side. From this clearly we have that in LINQ-to-SQL the `DateTime.Now.AddDays()` "works" (because that part of the expression is fully evaluated .NET-side) while on EF it doesn't, because the SQL doesn't have an `AddDays()` that works "exactly" as the .NET `AddDays()` (the `DATEADD` works with integers, not floating points).

Is it more correct what the LINQ-to-SQL does or what the EF does? I'll say that it's more correct what the EF does (even if it's more "strange")...

Example: what would happen if the .NET app and the SQL app were on two different timezones (so with different times)... Would it be more correct that the `DateTime.Now` was the .NET time or the SQL time? I think the second one (but I repeat, if I had discovered this as a "bug" in my app, even I would have made a big ooooooh).

As a sidenote (not very important), you shouldn't calculate twice the date in the same place and think that they'll be equal. This time you used the full date, so no problems, but if you had taken only the `DateTime.Now.Date`, and if you code was executed around midnight, perhaps, very very perhaps the two dates would be different, because one is calculated on 23:59:59.9999999 while the other is calculated on 00:00:00.0000000 of the next day.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that EF is trying to convert and then execute your query on the `SQL` side. And there is no [`System.DateTime.AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) equivalent in there. 
So `DateTime.AddDays` method is not a either canonical or database function and cannot be converted to proper command tree node for further execution. Normally you should use **SqlFunctions** or **EntityFunctions** in your queries. But still there is a way to invoke custom database functions by defining them in your ***.edmx*** file.

Also take into consideration that **LINQ to Entities** *does not* support some of standard query methods: `Aggregate`, `Last`, etc. and a lot of overloads like `Select<TSource, TResult>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>>)`. 
Full list of supported operators  is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx).

---

To fix this you should use [`EntityFunctions.AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412479.aspx):
Replace `DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1)` with `EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, 1);`

Comment: LINQ to SQL handles this much more elegantly, it wraps the values in the where into parameters and passes them into SQL and then produces SQL like this `([t0].[EventDate] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[EventDate] <= @p1)`.

Comment: It dismays me that Entity Framework still doesn't manage to do something as simple as this after 5 versions when LINQ to SQL supported it out of the box.

Comment: @DoctorJones - It dismays me that L2S would silently use client-side values for things you would expect to be done server-side.  EF doesn't do this deliberately, because doing so would be give incorrect results.

Comment: @MystereMan Given that EF does nothing about `DateTime.Now` (it uses the CLR value in the query, and not a "current date and time" on the SQL server), it is exceedingly stupid that invoking `.AddDays(n)` on that same value causes it to fail instead of resolving the parameter to the modified value. As such, this is not an issue of where you would expect code to execute, which in turn makes the criticism of EF entirely valid.

Answer (score 0):

You may store these days in a variable as well:

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1);
```

and in the Where:

```
.Where(e => 
    e.EventDate >= yesterday  && 
    e.EventDate <= tomorrow 
)
```